# To format standard phone field for indian format i.e. without any space and brackects

Tags: standard-objects

I want to change the standard phone field of salesforce according to indian phone format i.e. it should be a 10 digit number without any space,brackets and hyphens.
Ex-9898765456 
and not (982) 008-8498 which comes by default.
Can it be done without coding??
I don't want to use + sign.
I want when a client saves a phone number it should be saved by default to a 10 digit number without any spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow with this formula evaluation :

```
BEGINS(Phone,'+')
```

And create a workflow action of type field update with formula like below:

```
RIGHT( Phone,10)
```

I hope this will help.

Ask me for more help.

Comment: No,it is not working.

Comment: I tried it by myself in my org and it worked. do you want any screencast of workflow creation for help

Comment: yes please.Not working in my org.

Comment: get screencast from this link https://youtu.be/rE5zjZ1BR3A

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge. Create a WF with rule criteria which evaluates whenever the Phone field is Not Null or as per the requirement. Update the phone field by field update WF action and use below formula in field update formula editor. (It is only for 10 digit number.)
Let me know if this helps or not.

RIGHT(LEFT(LEFT(Phone, 5),4),3) 
& MID(Phone, 7, 3) & RIGHT(Phone, 4)

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow on any object like Contact .

Then create an immediate workflow field  update action  on Phone Field .

And put that formula in formula Editor.

**RIGHT(  SUBSTITUTE(  SUBSTITUTE(  SUBSTITUTE(  SUBSTITUTE( Phone ,"-","")  , " ", "")  , ")","")  ,"(",""),10)**